# Does apache ignite writes to work/marshaller directory, if persistance is not enabled?

Tags: ignite

I have two different ignite deployments. In both, Apache Ignite server is started from the java program. The program sets work directory, configures the logger and then starts the server.

I have web application (Apache Ignite Client), which connects to respective Apache Ignite Server and performs the operation on cache.

What I am observing is that, in one enviroment some files are created inside **work/marshaller** directory and in other deployment the **marshaller** folder is empty.

Persistence is not enabled.

Can anyone explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ignite would write to marshaller dir when a corresponding type is used. This is because it is possible to have situation when all nodes which knew what type corresponding to a given typeId has left, and the remaining can no longer make sense of data they possess.